# What is the difference between Database Migration Testing and Data Migration Testing?

Tags: testing

I am a beginner.I would like to know the basic differences between Database Migration and Data Migration Testings.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suggest a Google search!

Answer (score 0):

There is no much difference between database migration testing or data migration testing. Some folks will use database or db or data. In my opinion database migration refers to moving the all the components from legacy system to new database system like procedures, jobs, scripts etc, where as data migration means the historical data which is already there in tables from so many years by ran by legacy jobs. This data should be copied to new systems tables and a lot of testing is involved. The testing is somewhat difference for the both the things.

you can get more details at this location.
http://www.handyinsight.com/2016/04/database-migration-testing.html

hope this helps..